# How to refactor the following code

Tags: generics, refactoring

Hi the below BackendHubProxy inherit Hub, I also another class to use GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext();

What is better to refactor the below?

```
    private static void OnGamesDisabled(Guid playerId)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BackendHubProxy>();
        hubContext.Clients.User(playerId.ToString("N")).DisablePlayer();
    }

    private static void OnGamesDeauthorized(Guid playerId)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BackendHubProxy>();
        hubContext.Clients.User(playerId.ToString("N")).DeauthorizePlayer();
    }

    private static void OnGamesChanged(string[] lobbyClientIds)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FrontendHubProxy>();
        hubContext.Clients.Groups(lobbyClientIds).GamesChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't clearly state what your end goal is, but assuming you are trying to eliminate duplication, duplication could be extracted to one method.

```
private static Clients getClients()
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BackendHubProxy>();
    return hubContext.Clients;
}

private static void OnGamesDisabled(Guid playerId)
{
    getClients().User(playerId.ToString("N")).DisablePlayer();
}

private static void OnGamesDeauthorized(Guid playerId)
{
    getClients().User(playerId.ToString("N")).DeauthorizePlayer();
}

private static void OnGamesChanged(string[] lobbyClientIds)
{
    getClients().Groups(lobbyClientIds).GamesChanged();
}
```

Comment: how about 
    private static void OnGamesChanged(string[] lobbyClientIds)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FrontendHubProxy>();
        hubContext.Clients.Groups(lobbyClientIds).GamesChanged();
    }
how will you refactor ?

Comment: @letitbe you could leave it out of the refactoring. Mostly I am wondering what dialect you are using. My java 7 env didn't like it. I would need something I could compile to work with the different types of HubProxies.
You could pass a flag into GetHubContext to work choose the type.